# Static Analysis erroneously reports out of bounds access

Tags: static-analysis, frama-c

While reviewing a codebase, I came upon a particular piece of code that triggered a warning regarding an "out of bounds access". After looking at the code, I could not see a way for the reported access to happen - and tried to minimize the code to create a reproducible example. I then checked this example with two commercial static analysers that I have access to - and also with the open-source Frama-C.

All 3 of them see the same "out of bounds" access.

I don't. Let's have a look:

```
 3  extern int checker(int id);
 4  extern int checker2(int id);
 5  
 6  int compute(int *q)
 7  {
 8      int res = 0, status;
 9  
10      status = checker2(12);
11      if (!status) {
12          status = 1;
13          *q = 2;
14          for(int i=0; i<2 && 0!=status; i++) {
15              if (checker(i)) {
16                  res = i;
17                  status=checker2(i);
18              }
19          }
20      }
21      if (!status)
22          *q = res;
23      return status;
24  }
25  
26  int someFunc(int id)
27  {
28      int p;
29      extern int data[2];
30  
31      int status = checker2(132);
32      status |= compute(&p);
33      if (status == 0) {
34          return data[p];
35      } else
36          return -1;
37  }
```

*Please don't try to judge the quality of the code, or why it does things the way it does*. This is a hacked, cropped and mutated version of the original, with the sole intent being to reach a small example that demonstrates the issue.

All analysers I have access to report the same thing - that the indexing in the caller at line 34, doing the `return data[p]` may read via the invalid index "2". Here's the output from Frama-C - but note that two commercial static analysers provide exactly the same assessment:

```
$ frama-c -val -main someFunc -rte why.c |& grep warning
...
why.c:34:[value] warning: accessing out of bounds index. assert p < 2;
```

Let's step the code in reverse, to see how this out of bounds access at line 34 can happen:

- To end up in line 34, the returned `status` from both calls to `checker2` and `compute` should be 0.
- For `compute` to return 0 (at line 32 in the caller, line 23 in the callee), it means that we have performed the assignment at line 22 - since it is guarded at line 21 with a check for `status` being 0. So we wrote in the passed-in pointer `q`, whatever was stored in variable `res`. This pointer points to the variable used to perform the indexing - the supposed out-of-bounds index.
- So, to experience an out of bounds access into the `data`, which is dimensioned to contain exactly two elements, we must have written a value that is neither 0 nor 1 into `res`.
- We write into `res` via the `for` loop at 14; which will conditionally assign into `res`; if it *does* assign, the value it will write will be one of the two valid indexes 0 or 1 - because those are the values that the `for` loop allows to go through (it is bound with `i<2`).
- Due to the initialization of `status` at line 12, if we do reach line 12, we will for sure enter the loop at least once. And if we do write into `res`, we will write a nice valid index.
- What if we don't write into it, though? The "default" setup at line 13 has written a "2" into our target - **which is probably what scares the analysers**. Can that "2" indeed escape out into the caller?
- Well, it doesn't seem so... if the `status` checks - at either line 11 or at line 21 fail, we will return with a non-zero `status`; so whatever value we wrote (or didn't, and left uninitialised) into the passed-in `q` is irrelevant; the caller will not read that value, due to the check at line 33.

So either I am missing something and there is indeed a scenario that leads to an out of bounds access with index 2 at line 34 (how?) or this is an example of the limits of mainstream formal verification.

Help?

Comment: "Please don't try to judge the quality of the code, or why it does things the way it does." -- this is Stack Overflow, c'mon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### When dealing with a case such as having to distinguish between `== 0` and `!= 0` inside a range, such as `[INT_MIN; INT_MAX]`, you need to tell Frama-C/Eva to split the cases.

By adding `//@ split` annotations in the appropriate spots, you can tell Frama-C/Eva to maintain separate states, thus preventing merging them before `status` is evaluated.

Here's how your code would look like, in this case (courtesy of @Virgile):

```c
extern int checker(int id);
extern int checker2(int id);

int compute(int *q)
{
  int res = 0, status;
  status = checker2(12);
  //@ split status <= 0;
  //@ split status == 0;
  if (!status) {
    status = 1;
    *q = 2;
    for(int i=0; i<2 && 0!=status; i++) {
      if (checker(i)) {
        res = i;
        status=checker2(i);
      }
    }
  }
  //@ split status <= 0;
  //@ split status == 0;
  if (!status)
    *q = res;
  return status;
}

int someFunc(int id)
{
  int p;
  extern int data[2];

  int status = checker2(132);
  //@ split status <= 0;
  //@ split status == 0;
  status |= compute(&p);
  if (status == 0) {
    return data[p];
  } else
    return -1;
}
```

In each case, the first `split` annotation tells Eva to consider the cases `status <= 0` and `status > 0` separately; this allows "breaking" the interval `[INT_MIN, INT_MAX]` into `[INT_MIN, 0]` and `[1, INT_MAX]`; the second annotation allows separating `[INT_MIN, 0]` into `[INT_MIN, -1]` and `[0, 0]`. When these 3 states are propagated separately, Eva is able to precisely distinguish between the different situations in the code and avoid the spurious alarm.

You also need to allow Frama-C/Eva some margin for keeping the states separated (by default, Eva will optimize for efficiency, merging states somewhat aggressively); this is done by adding `-eva-precision 1` (higher values may be required for your original scenario).

#### Related options: `-eva-domains sign` (previously `-eva-sign-domain`) and `-eva-partition-history N`

Frama-C/Eva also has other options which are related to splitting states; one of them is the *signs domain*, which computes information about sign of variables, and is useful to distinguish between 0 and non-zero values. In some cases (such as a slightly simplified version of your code, where `status |= compute(&p);` is replaced with `status = compute(&p);`), the sign domain may help splitting without the need for annotations. Enable it using `-eva-domains sign` (`-eva-sign-domain` for Frama-C <= 20).

Another related option is `-eva-partition history N`, which tells Frama-C to keep the states partitioned for longer.

Note that keeping states separated is a bit costly in terms of analysis, so it may not scale when applied to the "real" code, if it contains several more branches. Increasing the values given to `-eva-precision` and `-eva-partition-history` may help, as well as adding `@ split` annotations.

I'd like to add some remarks which will hopefully be useful in the future:

#### Using Frama-C/Eva effectively

Frama-C contains several plug-ins and analyses. Here in particular, you are using the *Eva* plug-in. It performs an analysis based on abstract interpretation that reports all possible runtime errors (*undefined behaviors*, as the C standard puts it) in a program. Using `-rte` is thus unnecessary, and adds noise to the result. If Eva cannot be certain about the absence of some alarm, it will report it.

Replace the `-val` option with `-eva`. It's the same thing, but the former is deprecated.

If you want to improve precision (to remove false alarms), add `-eva-precision N`, where `0 <= N <= 11`. In your example program, it doesn't change much, but in complex programs with multiple callstacks, extra precision will take longer but minimize the number of false alarms.

Also, consider providing a minimal specification for the external functions, to avoid warnings; here they contain no pointers, but if they did, you'd need to provide an *assigns* clause to explicitly tell Frama-C whether the functions modify such pointers (or any global variables, for instance).

#### Using the GUI and Studia

With the Frama-C graphical interface and the Studia plug-in (accessible by right-clicking an expression of interest and choosing the popup menu Studia -> Writes), and using the *Values* panel in the GUI, you can easily track what the analysis inferred, and better understand where the alarms and values come from. The only downside is that, it does not report *exactly* where merges happen. For the most precise results possible, you may need to add calls to an Eva built-in, `Frama_C_show_each(exp)`, and put it inside a loop to get Eva to display, at each iteration of its analysis, the values contained in `exp`.

See section 9.3 (Displaying intermediate results) of the [Eva user manual](http://frama-c.com/download/frama-c-eva-manual.pdf) for more details, including similar built-ins (such as `Frama_C_domain_show_each` and `Frama_C_dump_each`, which show information about abstract domains). You may need to `#include "__fc_builtin.h"` in your program. You can use `#ifdef __FRAMAC__` to allow the original code to compile when including this Frama-C-specific file.

#### Being nitpicky about the term *erroneous reports*

Frama-C is a semantic-based tool whose main analyses are *exhaustive*, but may contain *false positives*: Frama-C may report alarms when they do not happen, but it should never *forget* any possible alarm. It's a trade-off, you can't have an exact tool in all cases (though, in this example, with sufficient -eva-precision, Frama-C is exact, as in reporting only issues which may actually happen).

In this sense, *erroneous* would mean that Frama-C "forgot" to indicate some issue, and we'd be really concerned about it. Indicating an alarm where it may not happen is still problematic for the user (and we work to improve it, so such situations should happen less often), but not a *bug* in Frama-C, and so we prefer using the term *imprecisely*, e.g. "Frama-C/Eva imprecisely reports an out of bounds access".

Comment: If the call to checker2 at line 17 returns 0, and we are at the last iteration, "res" was just assigned to 1. This means that at the second "if" (line 21) we assign "1" to "*q" - so everything is fine - no?

Comment: I do appreciate all the rest of the information in your answer, though - thanks a lot for that. It just so happens that somehow this code confuses all analysers I've thrown at it - including Frama-C (making them report this false positive). Allow me to say that from a user viewpoint, whether we call it "an error" of Sound Static Analysis or a limitation of abstract interpretation or whatever, my point is that analysers miss the correlation between the returned "status" and the possible value set written in "p". My impression so far is that this (variable correlation) is a general SA limit.

Comment: Indeed, I misread the code when running in the GUI, I'll fix the answer.

Comment: In the general case, you are right that this correlation between the returned status and the possible value written in `p` is hard to maintain. Indeed, static analyses need to choose between precision and efficiency, otherwise they will just act as interpreters, trying each value separately. Your case resembles the situation of a *sentinel value*, in which a specific value inside a range has a special meaning, and keeping it separate from the others is important. There are specific domains in abstract interpretation for that, but all are not yet implemented in Frama-C.

Comment: By the way, in my previous answer, I had actually modified the code locally for testing and forgot to restore it in the end. So the proposed answer did not work in your example. After some help and fixes, this new version should hopefully work (tested with Frama-C 21.0 Scandium). I rewrote the comments since they may still be handy for similar code.

Comment: Just finished installing the latest `frama-c-base` in a Debian unstable chroot (the `frama-c-base` package in Debian buster doesn't support the options you recommended). Sadly, I got an "undefined symbol: camlWhy3__Trans__seq_303" when I tried to launch `frama-c -eva ...`. I guess I'll try again in a couple of months. Thanks for the suggestions, @anoi and @Virgile, I hope Debian unstable will catch up soon with them.

Comment: The Debian packages are not provided by us, and unfortunately the latest ones seem to lack the why3 dependencies (which do not prevent compilation but fail at loading, so the Debian process must have missed them). We'll try to contact Debian packagers to fix it, but ideally `opam` is the recommended way. We also provide some docker images (https://hub.docker.com/r/framac/frama-c), in case it could help.

Comment: Thank you! And indeed, please notify the Debian maintainers, they should fix this.